# Can I call function within a thread? C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to improve the speed of a certain C application and for that I will be using threads. What concerns me is if I can, within a function being executed in a different thread, call another function of that is not being executed in the same thread: Example:

```
void checks_if_program_can_do_something()
{

}

void does_something()
{
    checks_if_program_can_do_something();
}
int main()
{
    does_something(); //another thread is used to execute this function
    return 1;
}
```

In this case, the function does_something() calls the function checks_if_program_can_do_something(), but does_something() is being executed in another thread. I hope I made myself clear. Can I also call the function checks_if_program_can_do_something() in other functions using multiple threads?

Comment: Function call/return does not change thread context.  Since your main() function is run by a thread, (it's created by the process loader), this should be pretty obvious.  So, yes, call away,. with the usual caveats about globals, statics and other non-thread-safe data.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about threads. In my area of work we do code in C but nothing too complex. I just want to make my program faster as I'll be adding more stuff into the application and the Raspberry Pi used to run the project may not be fast enough to handle  all the processes sequentially, hence why my idea of threads.

Comment: Duet o context switching and similar, a multi threaded program will be slower, unless the threads are spending lots of time waiting for I/O, etc.

Comment: @user3629249 or if there are multiple cores.

Comment: Are you asking if more than one thread can call the same function at the same time?

Comment: If you are going to learn to use threads, then it's time to stop talking about a function that _does_ this, or a function that _does_ that.  Functions don't _do_ anything.  A function is just a list of instructions---like a list of chores to do in the kitchen.  If I give you a list of chores, it's not my list that washed the dishes, it was you, _executing_ my instructions.  The thing that executes instructions in a program is called a "thread."  Threads _do_ things.  Functions are just there so that the threads know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you should take care that the function does not alter state in such a way that other threads would be impacted negatively.

The terms related to this kind of protection are `reentrant`, which means the program can safely be paused and continued, and `thread-safe` which means that two non-pausing calls can be made at the same time.

These features you add to a function require programming approaches that might differ from most people's standard approaches; but, they handle two important scenarios that must be accounted for when writing threaded code:

- The CPU pauses part of your program (it needs to wait on I/O) or needs the core for a different part of your program.
- The CPU decides to run two threads of your program at the same time on different cores.

Gide lines for safe programming approaches are plentiful, but [I've provided one here for you to get started](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/writing_reentrant_thread_safe_code.htm).  Keep in mind that if you use someone else's code in a threaded situation, you also need to verify that their code is written to be reentrant / thread safe.